# Changing code in a loop - Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, loops, optimization, cocos2d-iphone

I am writing a 2-D game using cocos2d for iOS, and I have a lot of Sprite Objects for each game layer class.

So for the initialization of these sprites in a game layer, I have a lot of code that does pretty much the same thing for each object. What I want to know is, instead of doing this 30 times in my initialization code:

```
    self.sprite1 = [InteractiveSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"herospriteB04.png"];
    self.sprite1.spriteCode = 1;

    self.sprite1.orientation = 3;
    if (self.hero.sprite1_Orientation)
    {
        self.sprite1.orientation = self.hero.sprite1_Orientation;
    }
    if (self.sprite1.orientation == 1)
    {
        [self.sprite1 setDisplayFrame:[[spriteBWalkDown frames] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else if (self.sprite1.orientation == 2)
    {
        [self.sprite1 setDisplayFrame:[[spriteBWalkUp frames] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else if (self.sprite1.orientation == 3)
    {
        [self.sprite1 setDisplayFrame:[[spriteBWalkRight frames] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.sprite1 setDisplayFrame:[[spriteBWalkLeft frames] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }

    [self schedule:@selector(updateSprite1) interval:(2.0f)];

    if (self.hero.sprite1position.x != 0)
    {
        self.sprite1.position = self.hero.sprite1position;
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *sprite1start = [objects objectNamed:@"spriteStart1"];
        double x1 = [[sprite1start valueForKey:@"x"]floatValue];
        double y1 = [[sprite1start valueForKey:@"y"]floatValue];
        self.sprite1.position = ccp(x1,y1);
    }

    [self.theHKMap addChild:sprite1 z:self.bgLayer.zOrder];

    CGPoint tileCoord1 = [self tileCoordForPosition:sprite1.position];    
    int tileGID1 = [self.bgLayer tileGIDAt:tileCoord1];
    [self.bgLayer removeTileAt:tileCoord1];
    [self.bgLayer setTileGID:(tileGID1 + 1) at:tileCoord1];
```

The above is very long and unwieldy, I don't like having 30x that much code in each separate map class.

So my question: How would a veteran programmer go about putting something like this into a loop, so that every instance of the string sprite1 can be replaced with sprite2, etc.?

To my knowledge, even if you could 'create' code in a loop, it wouldn't matter at compile time, which of course is more important than code length. Unless there is a significant optimization in the compiled code, I probably won't change it, even if it does reduce the length of the code and thereby make XCode syntax highlighting less laggy. Either way, though, I'm very curious about some workarounds people have thought of. Thanks

Comment: Don't refactor your code to make the compiler happy - refactor your code to make *yourself* happy. And by happy, I mean not insane. And by yourself, I mean the future you.

Comment: I would store the 30 sprites in an `NSArray` object and refer to each object as `sprites[i]`. That would allow me to go through a loop with index `i` and perform the same operation 30 times.

Comment: I feel pretty dumb for not thinking of that godel. That would certainly make things clearer...

Comment: make a function that takes a sprite as a parameter, pass in the sprite you want to modify